# При поиске элементов на странице с помощью Selenium Python получаю обратно пустой список

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

На странице есть, например, следующий элемент:

`<div class="iconTabSheet139_1 PPTSPicture " style="width: 16px; height: 16px; left: 28.5px; top: 5.5px; background-size: cover; cursor: pointer;"></div>`

Есть еще несколько элементов с таким же классом. Я пыталась их найти следующим образом:

```
elements = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.iconTabSheet139_1.PPTSPicture')
```

Однако я получаю пустой список:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так и как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получаешь пустой список, потому что ищешь **CSS** стили методом **find_elements_by_css_selector**, а пишешь **классы**.

Если есть несколько таких элементов на странице - сделай с помощью **XPath**.
Есть множество замечательных расширений для браузера, например - XPath Finder

Пример как использовать:

```py
element = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[11]/div/div/div[1]/button/span') 
#Второе значение - то, что выдаст расширение
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась с помощью xpath:

```
elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'iconTabSheet139_1 PPTSPicture')]")
```